# Why is a Star Schema more normalized than a 3NF Schema?

Tags: database-design, normalization

According to [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10810/schemas.htm#CIHEDBDD), third normal form schemas "may require less data-transformation than more normalized schemas such as star schemas".

I'm confused, I thought 3NF is the most normalized among common schema models, then goes snowflake schema and at last star schema.

Comment: Perhaps it's a typo and they meant "__less__ normalized schemas ..."

Comment: "3NF is the most normalized among common schema models", this is not true as there are more normal forms than 3.

Comment: 3NF is the most common though, I think that's what @Yrogirg meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ypercube stated this seems to be a typo and should be changed to "more **de**-normalized schemas". One of the following paragraphsinthe Oracle manual states:

Snowflake schemas normalize dimensions to eliminate redundancy. That is, the dimension data has been grouped into multiple tables instead of one large table. For example, a product dimension table in a star schema might be normalized into a products table, a product_category table, and a product_manufacturer table in a snowflake schema.

This product dimension table of the star schema described here is not in third normal form  but are results of joining (denormalize) some tables of the snowflake schema.

I found aricles on the web that describe why a star schema is not in 3rd normal form [link](http://www.coffingdw.com/articles/StarSchema.htm) [link](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/oracle-tip-understand-the-difference-between-star-and-snowflake-schemas-in-olap/5221690)